# How to pass a parameter into rendered attribute?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I try to pass a parameter into method admin like this:

```xml
<p:toolbarGroup align="right" rendered="#{loginBean.admin('dataread'}">
                            <h:form>
                                <p:commandButton value="manage users" ajax="false"
                                                 icon="ui-icon-document" action="/admin/manageUsers.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"/>
                            </h:form>
                        </p:toolbarGroup>
```

the code in my managed Bean is like that

```java
public boolean isAdmin(String role){
          FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
          HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
          return request.isUserInRole("admin");                
          }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
rendered="#{loginBean.admin('dataread'}"
```

You've there with the missing `)` an EL syntax error which causes the value not being recognized as an EL expression and is thus treated as a plain vanilla string which would in the `rendered` attribute thus default to boolean `true`. Also, when specifying action expressions like `#{bean.method()}` instead of value expressions like `#{bean.property}`, you should specify the full method name, thus `isAdmin()` instead of `admin()`.

All with all, this should do:

```
rendered="#{loginBean.isAdmin('dataread')}"
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `HttpServletRequest` is already available in the EL scope by `#{request}`, so this should also do without the need for backing bean boilerplate:

```
rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('admin')}"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Correct syntax**:

```
rendered="#{loginBean.isAdmin('dataread')}">
```

instead of

```
rendered="#{loginBean.admin('dataread'}"
```

**Make sure your EL supports such feature**:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Look for more information containing tutorials on passing parameters in JSF:

- [How to pass parameters in method expression – JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-pass-parameters-in-method-expression-jsf-2-0/)
- [4 ways to pass parameter from JSF page to backing bean](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/)