# rendered in JSF with method parameter

Tags: java, jsf

I am creating a xhtml that uses JSF. I have a class called SeguridadControllerBean.java which contains a method isRol (String role)
This method I want to call from the XHTML by passing the parameter as follows:

```html
<h:outputText value = "The Producers"
   rendered = "#{seguridad.rol ['administrator']}" />
```

But the problem is that when you arrive at this screen, it tells me the following:

```
javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/view/template.xhtml @18,54 rendered="#{seguridad.rol['administrator']}": Bean: org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_559, property: rol
```

Now, if I remove the parameter and the method isRol () does not receive any parameters, it works.

Comment: The error is very explicit. There's no `rol` attribute for `seguridad` bean (or request/session/application attribute). Looks like the proxy object generated by javassist haven't loaded the `rol` field, thus generating this exception. Or the `rol` attribute is not a map =\

Comment: So.. how i can do to load the method rol??

Comment: But.. the rol is a method.. not attribute!

Comment: Again, that's the problem. The EL resolver expects `seguridad.rol` as a field in `seguridad` class type with its respective getter following JavaBean conventions. Since it is not, it will throw the exception you're reading. To solve the problem, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/10726462/1065197

Comment: I saw the solution and now I call it as follows:

rendered = "# {rendered = seguridad.isRol ('administrator')}"

But I miss another error:

/ WEB-INF/view/template.xhtml @ 18,56 rendered = "# {seguridad.isRol ('administrator')}" Error Parsing: # {seguridad.isRol ('administrator')}

Comment: Please edit your question and add (do not remove) the new code and problems you're getting.

Comment: And if possible, put the signature of method `isRol` please.

Comment: Is your class SeguridadControllerBean.java annotated `@Named("seguridad")`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your XHTML like this...

```
     <h:outputText value = "The Producers"
   rendered = "#{seguridad.rol('administrator')}" />
```